# Image not resizing dynamically with window size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want an image with the size of 250x50px to resize itself (go smaller) according to the window size, in other words, make it responsive.

The `#wrapper` holds the content for the whole page. The `#header`holds the image and the navigation bar.

I know this may be easier with the use of `@media screen`but I am looking for a pure CSS approach.

Here is what I am currently using:

**HTML**:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="header"> 
             <div style="max-width:500px;">
                 <img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" href="#"> 
         </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#header{
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#logo{
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: `@media` queries _are_ pure CSS...

Comment: You mean smaller than that `min-width: 300px;` on your `#header`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few issues in your code,

- don't use inline-styles,
- put the `border-bottom` in child `div` of `#header`
- no need for IE hacks
- no need for a `min-width` here.

**Note:**  I don't see why you need this image to get smaller, lets see, its `250x50`, when the lower screen are `320px` so already fits perfectly

here is a snippet

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: dashed red 1px
}
#header > div {
  max-width: 500px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div>
      <img id="logo" src="//placehold.it/250x50" alt="logo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Especially the `min-width` on the header.  If you want it to go smaller than `250px` I can't fathom why they'd set a `min-width` on the header of `300px`.  Might want to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, using @media screen is a CSS approach. But if you don't want that, you can just relative units like em or % and give a min-width:

```
#logo {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

thing is, you already put some limits by setting the header to min width 300px and the div inside to max width 500px, so if you want to have more flexibility with those as well, consider different units too.